# Why do I get a java.lang.NoSuchFieldError on web application with JSF?

Tags: primefaces, atmosphere, primefaces-push

I am working on web application with JSF and I try to make notifications by Primefaces Push but when I run the project I got this exception :

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: framework
at org.primefaces.push.PushServlet.configureFramework(PushServlet.java:66)
at org.primefaces.push.PushServlet.configureFramework(PushServlet.java:36)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:74)
```

Also I added this Libraries :

> primefaces 5.0 atmosphere-runtime-2.3.5 slf4j-api-1.7.7 commons-lang3-3.4

Comment: Where does it state that you need (can use) atmosphere 2.3.5 for PF 5.0? [this](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_0/pom.xml#L150) does not, nor does the documentation, releasenotes etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an Atmosphere version that is compatible with PrimeFaces 5.0. That is 2.1.3 according to the docs, [pom](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_0/pom.xml#L150) and releasenotes.